# An electron leaves a neutral droplet. After that, a singly-charged positive ion joins the droplet. What is the resulting charge of the droplet?

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, charge, ions

I know an electron's charge is $~1.6 × 10^{-19} C$, which would mean that after leaving it would leave the droplets charge as $+1.6 × 10^{-19} C$ (right?) but I do not understand the effect of the ion on the charge of the droplet.